# Use text function inside a gui

Tags: matlab

I want to use the text function to add some info to a curve in a gui. But the problem is that when I set the coordinates and specify the handles to the figure I don't get anything shown on the figure. The text just doesn't show anything. The code is inside a for loop. But here's a small portion of my code containing the text functions..

I have defined some matrices d, s, c, J, and mi somewhere else..

```
animh=handles.runAnimationOnAxes;
V=s*Es+c*0.7053*Z^2/A^(1/3)+...
J(it).*(J(it)+1)*(hbar)^2./(2*(mi*2/5*M*r0^2*A^(2/3)+...
4*M*a^2));

p=polyfit(d,V,5);
pol=p(1)*d.^5 + p(2)*d.^4+p(3)*d.^3+p(4)*d.^2+p(5)*d+p(6);

plot(animh,d,pol,'k')
ylabel(animh,'$V(r/R_0)\ (Mev)$','interpreter','latex',...
'FontSize',11);
xlabel(animh,'$r/R_0$','interpreter','latex',...
'FontSize',11);
xlim(animh,[0.3 2.5]);
ylim(animh,[Ymin Ymax]);
title(animh,'MLDM potential energy surface');

indexmin = find(min(pol) == pol);
xmin = d(indexmin);
ymin = pol(indexmin);

indexmax = find(max(pol) == pol);
xmax = d(indexmax);
ymax = pol(indexmax);

strmin = ['Minimum = ',num2str(ymin)];
text(animh,xmin,ymin,strmin);

strmax = ['Maximum = ',num2str(ymax)];
text(animh,xmax,ymax,strmax);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`text` function](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/text.html) does not have, within its input parameters the `handle` of the `axes` on which to add the string.

Actually, the first two input should be the `x coord` and the `y coord` of the point in which to add the string.

Moreover, `text` can be used to add strings also in 3D graphs, so in your instructions

```
text(animh,xmin,ymin,strmin);
```

and

```
text(animh,xmax,ymax,strmax);
```

the axes handle is interpreted as the `x coord`, while `xmax` and `ymax`, respectively as `y coord` and `z coord`.

If in your GUI you have only one `axes` you just have to remove the first parameter in the calls to `text`.

If in your GUI you have more than one `axes` you should make the `axes` in which you want to add the string the "current axes":

EDIT: removed the first parameter in the call to `text`

```
axes(handles.runAnimationOnAxes)

strmin = ['Minimum = ',num2str(ymin)];
text(xmin,ymin,strmin);

strmax = ['Maximum = ',num2str(ymax)];
text(xmax,ymax,strmax);
```

Hope this helps.

Qapla'

Comment: thanks for the answer. I have two GUIs and there are actually many axes that have their own handles. But this piece of code resides in the second GUI where it's called by the first GUI. In the second GUI there is only one plot so nothing more to confuse. But I actually removed the first parameter as you said but again nothing happened. I don't know how to deal with that.

Comment: Did you check the values of `xmin`, `ymin` and `xmax`, `ymax`? Are they "within" the graph? (I've updated the last part of the code, now the call is without the axes handle).

Comment: Actually, I have checked them all. They are all within the graph. The only problem is that the text function can't recognize the graph to which it's supposed to add the texts. Also I removed the axes handles but again nothing.

Comment: Did you set `axes(handles.runAnimationOnAxes)` before the call to `text`? Could you try `th=text(xmax,ymax,strmax);` and then `get(th)`? What do you read on the CommandWindow?

Comment: Is `runAnimationOnAxes` the right `axes` on which to add the string?

Comment: Oops, thank you very much:) I didn't use `axes(handles.runAnimationOnAxes)` on top of the text and doing that solved my problem. I now can see both the texts appear on the graph. Thank you really really. May you now tell me why it did solve the problem?